# UITableView headerView with custom UIView

Tags: ios, uitableview

YJHomeViewContoller.m

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [YJHeaderView view];
}
```

YJHeadView.m:

```
+ (instancetype)view
{
    YJHeaderView *view = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YJHeaderView" owner:nil options:nil] lastObject];
}
```

YJHeaderView is my custom view,I use xib to describe.There is a UISWitch in the YJHeaderView.**The problem is** when i run the application,the UISwitch can't be touched.

Comment: Did you implement heightForHeader method?

Comment: have you given UISWitch userinteraction enabled to yes?